# XML Deserialization to C# weird XML and weirder class generated

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I have read multiple threads and I am able to deserialize XML utilizing the serialization methods form C#. The issue that i am having is that the XML that i was provided is not like I've seen before. And instead of having an object that contains a list of items i get an object with one item that contains multiple properties.  Here is what i have. This is the XML:

```
<DATA>
    <OBJECT TYPE="Sheet consumption">
        <ITEM>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Sheet">GN18 48x120</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Sheet used area">31.556835306782627</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Made quantity">2</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Required quantity">2</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Sheet weight">34.132561</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Sheet width">1219.2</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Sheet length">3048</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Sheet thickness">1.1684</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Real time">0.712</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Production order">139020</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Item">W220-09528</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Quantity/Sheet">55</PROPERTY>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Sheet">GN20 48x120</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Sheet used area">35.895446716901191</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Made quantity">14</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Required quantity">14</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Sheet weight">26.618381</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Sheet width">1219.2</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Sheet length">3048</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Sheet thickness">0.9144</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Real time">0.414</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Production order">139019</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Item">W220-09533-C</PROPERTY>
            <PROPERTY NAME="Quantity/Sheet">7</PROPERTY>
        </ITEM>
    </OBJECT>
</DATA>
```

this is how the class looks like to deserialize

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

```
// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.0.30319.33440.
// 

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class DATA
    {

        private DATAOBJECT itemsField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("OBJECT")]
        public DATAOBJECT Items
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemsField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>

    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]

    public partial class DATAOBJECT
    {

        private List<DATAOBJECTITEMPROPERTY> iTEMField;

        private string tYPEField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem("PROPERTY", typeof(DATAOBJECTITEMPROPERTY), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public List<DATAOBJECTITEMPROPERTY> ITEM
        {
            get
            {
                return this.iTEMField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.iTEMField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string TYPE
        {
            get
            {
                return this.tYPEField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.tYPEField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class DATAOBJECTITEMPROPERTY
    {

        private string nAMEField;

        private string valueField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string NAME
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nAMEField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nAMEField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the result  when I deserialize that i would expect is to have 2 objects of type `DATAOBJECTITEMPROPERTY` but instead i get 24 objects of type `DATAOBJECTITEMPROPERTY` in which is basically each property name.

I dont get what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing wrong, the tool you used to generate your classes over complicated things and omitted a level.  I use an online generator like http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ to generate classed for me.

It produced much cleaner and easier to understand classes for your example.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "PROPERTY")]
public class PROPERTY
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "NAME")]
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ITEM")]
public class ITEM
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PROPERTY")]
    public List<PROPERTY> PROPERTY { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "OBJECT")]
public class OBJECT
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ITEM")]
    public List<ITEM> ITEM { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TYPE")]
    public string TYPE { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "DATA")]
public class DATA
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "OBJECT")]
    public List<OBJECT> OBJECT { get; set; }
}
```